# Program crashes on passing local variable address to shared pointer in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void func ()
{
    cout << "func\n";
    int localVariable = 10;
    int* p = new int;
    shared_ptr<int> ptr (&localVariable); 
    shared_ptr<int> ptr1 (new int); 
    shared_ptr<int> ptr2 (p); 
}

int main ()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to pass heap allocated memory directly to `shared_ptr` and also tried some pointer which is allocated before, both compile and run successfully.
But when i tried to pass local variable's address to `shared_ptr`, it crashed with following stack :

> vidhu@~/Documents/CPP_Practice$ ./a.out  func
>   *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfc7f13c ***
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Why this is happened ? I think deleting `NULL` pointer is safe but it is not good coding practice.

Comment: When `ptr` goes out of scope, its destructor essentially does `delete &localVariable;`, which exhibits undefined behavior as `&localVariable` is not a pointer obtained by `new`. I'm not sure what `NULL` pointer you are talking about.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik tried following too :
int* q = &localVariable;
shared_ptr<int> ptr3 (q);
Now i got double free or corruption (out) error. This pointer also not obtained by new. then why here i got double free error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Undefined behavior is undefined. If it hurts when you do this, then don't do that. What exactly are you driving at with this line of inquiry? Is there an actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shared_ptr` will try to delete the `localVariable` when `ptr` goes out of scope.  However, the `localVariable` is not heap allocated (via `new`), so it cannot be deleted (and is its memory is automatically managed by the stack).